# Having problems with dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

I'm using Elementor and created a custom header. I have a drop down menu for my service pages but it's blank. I added custom css to change the background to make it more visible.

I see the subpages in the drop down in the html, and I tried changing the text color of the links, but I can't figure it out.

https://houniqueconstruction.com/test/

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `display:none` applied to the class `.elementor-nav-menu ul`

Remove that if you have added that style. Or use `display: inline-block` or to override that style and display the menu items.

Also you may have to adjust the `top` css value because it's not displayed in the correct position in my screen.